# animate UIWebView content to white

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

So I have a UIView which has a UIWebView and I want so that it fades in to a white background from any kind of web site that I have opened. How do I do this? I guess having:

```
  [webView_ loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
```

in my animation block doesn't help. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a web developer, so I can't speak to how you might go about this using JavaScript, CSS, HTML, or anything else related.

I am an iOS developer, and I like the clevery stuff. You could add a transparent UIView on top of your webview, and animate a transition to opaque white, like so:

```
-(void)whiteout {
   UIView *superview = [webview superview]; // or [webview window];
   UIView *whiteout = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:webview.frame];
   whiteout.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   [superview addSubview:whiteout];
   [superview bringSubviewToFront:whiteout];

   [UIView beginAnimations:@"whiteout" context:nil];
   [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
   whiteout.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I think this will work, though I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something with JavaScript:

```
foreach element in html 
do
    animate element opacity to 0
done
```

I would look into jQuery for this.

Comment: @adit no clue man, I don't use JavaScript much, but good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to Richard's answer, but if you're looking to do this in the client side, you might place a solid white view the same size as the web view immediately behind it, then do:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
    animations:^{ webView.alpha = 0.0f; }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) { [webView removeFromSuperview]; }
];
```

As a rule of thumb, anything that `UIView` is clearly passing on to the `CALayer` is animatable, anything it's doing its own logic for isn't.